# Removing options from a dependent dropdown based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone please help me handle this issue in jQuery

I have a requirement where I have two dropdowns:

1. The no of floors of the flat (**numberOfFloors**)
2. The flat where the user stays (**whichFloorYouStay**)

I need to remove all the invalid options from the second dropdown. How do I achieve this?

For example: 
If a user select the **numberOfFloors** option as 3, then I should remove options 4 and 5 from **whichFloorYouStay** dropdown and just load 1,2,3 as **whichFloorYouStay** options.

Similarly, if a user select the **numberOfFloors** option as 1, then I should remove options 2,3,4,5 from **whichFloorYouStay** dropdown and just load 1 as **whichFloorYouStay** option.

Please find my JSBin link:
http://jsbin.com/sibufive/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //NEW CODE:
    var floorsvals = new Array();
    var lastvalue = Number.MAX_VALUE; //Useful for checking whether we need to append or remove elements - Initialize this with an arbitrarily large number

    //Fill possible floor vals with value of <option>'s
    $("#numberOfFloors option").each(function () {
        floorsvals.push($(this).val());
    });
    //NOTE: If you already know the values of the numberOfFloors array, you can just add those values straight into the "floorsvals" array
    //The above loop is just handy if you are dynamically generating a <select> list and don't already know the values

    $("#numberOfFloors").change(function () {
        alert($("#numberOfFloors").val());
        var value = $("#numberOfFloors").val();


        //NEW CODE:

        //If we need to append...
        if (value > lastvalue) { //This value is larger than the last value we just had
            for (i = 0; i < floorsvals.length; i++) {
                if (floorsvals[i] <= value && $('#whichFloorYouStay option[value=' + floorsvals[i] + ']').length === 0) { //Floor value is less than the selected maxvalue and an option with this floor value doesn't already exist...
                    $('<option value="' + floorsvals[i] + '">' + floorsvals[i] + '</option>').appendTo("#whichFloorYouStay"); //...So add that floor value
                }
            }
        } else { //Otherwise, we need to remove
            //OLD CODE:
            $('#whichFloorYouStay option').each(function () { //Go through each option
                if ($(this).val() > value) { //If this option's value is greater than the numberOfFloors value, remove it
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        }

        //NEW CODE:
        lastvalue = value; //Update last value chosen with this value

    });
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/sibufive/40/edit

Comment: Thanks. How do I append the values then. I selected 3 numberOfFloors then it loads 1,2,3 whichFloorYouStay. But now when I select 4 numberOfFloors I would need to see 1,2,3,4 whichFloorYouStay instead of the 1,2,3.

Comment: sorry you're right - this doesn't work - it'll just continue removing elements until there are none left - i updated the code so that there's a section of code that appends elements

Answer (score 0):

`var value = $("#numberOfFloors").val();`

should become

```
var value = $("#numberOfFloors").val();
value-=1
```

I would also suggest adding a value `0` to the first set of options one so you never have a user begin at `1` and try to move to the second menu